Can Diffie-Hellman (DH) be used to generate automated one-time passwords (OTPs) for each session without requiring user input?
I’m exploring the idea of using DH key exchange to generate a new shared secret for each authentication session, which both the user and the system would use to derive an OTP. This would eliminate the need for the user to see or enter the OTP, unlike traditional methods where each OTP is derived from the previous one or time-based factors. This really makes it stronger because knowing previous OTP has no relation to new one. Why don't people already use this simple thing or I am just being stupid.

No, Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange can not be used to generate automated One-Time Passwords for each session, much less so without requiring user input.
An OTP allows one party to authenticate w.r.t. the other, by way of a pre-shared secret that only the legitimate parties know. The device generating the OTP contains that secret, and whatever verifies the OTP also does, perhaps indirectly.
DHKE provides a secret shared between whatever the communicating parties are. It's not a substitute for OTP, for it does not provide authentication.
There exists Authenticated DHKE that does, and does not require user input at each session. But just like OTP it requires storage of a secret by the authenticated party. If we posit that, as in OTP, this secret is stored in a device (e.g. token, mobile phone) under control of the user who uses another device (e.g. computer, browser) to authenticate, then Authenticated DHKE is plain inappropriate, for the amount of data to transfer between the devices at each session would be so large as to be entirely impractical.
